# Tabs in Plain Text Files

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

In .txt files, I want to write a paragraph, with a tab in the front.

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
>   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
>   minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
>   aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

However, in my Sublime Text all preceding lines are indented according to the first tab.

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
>    eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et       dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
>    minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
>   aliquip       ex ea commodo consequat.

What are the settings to get the first format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to have the indentation on the first line instead of the whole paragraph, then you should add

`"indent_subsequent_lines": false,`

to your user settings (Preferences -> Settings -> User). I don't know if there's a way to restrict this configuration to .txt files only.

Comment: Preferences -> Settings - More -> Syntax Specific